# Finding mutually-distant vertices of a hypercube

Tags: normed-spaces

I want to choose a subset of vertices of an $n$-dimensional hypercube so that the Hamming distance between them is high. For instance, in 3 dimensions the following points are mutually 2 units apart:

$$
(0,0,0) \\
(1,1,0) \\
(1,0,1) \\
(0,1,1)
$$

Defining this formally:

For a subset $S\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$, let
$$
d(S) = \min_{a,b \in S} \left\lVert a-b \right\lVert_0
$$
(where $\left\lVert \cdot \right\lVert_0$ is the Hamming distance).

We can then ask

1. For a given distance $l$, what is the largest set $S$ so that $d(S) ≥ l$?
2. For a given set size $s$, what is the largest distance $d(S)$ such that $|S|≥s$?
3. (Fair variant) For a given distance $l$, what is the largest set $S$ such that $\left\lVert a-b \right\lVert_0 $ exactly equals $ l $ for all $a,b\in S$

For my application I would like an explicit construction of the fair variant for arbitrary dimensions. However the weaker '$\min$' forms seemed like they might be easier to analyze. I'm also a bit worried that my formulation might lead to degenerate solutions (e.g. $S=\{\mathtt{0}^n, \mathtt{1}^n\}$, so I tried to broaden the question. Feel free to include partial answers.

*Edit 2021-06-29*:

Phrasing it broadly seems to have been a mistake. Here's a concrete problem:

- Provide an algorithm to produce 4 $n$-bit strings ($n≥2$) such that (a) all pairs of strings have equal Hamming distance $l$, and (b) $l$ is maximal.

Comment: (1) and (2) are questions about optimal error detection/correction codes; there is a great amount of literature on the subject. For (3), the answer depends on $n$ and $l$ but is always at most $n+1$.

Comment: Searching for error detection codes did help me find some more results. For instance, Hamming(7,4) is an example for $l$=3, but is it optimal? What about higher $l$?

Comment: There is extensive literature on error correction/detection codes, and it's impossible to summarize it in a Stackexchange answer. If you asked a more specific question, it would be easier to answer it here. You can construct codes that detect $l$ errors for $l = 3$ or any $l > 3$. As a starting point, you may want to take a look at the Gilbert–Varshamov bound and some known constructions of error correcting codes. Also, regarding (3), take a look at Hadamard matrices.